# How to display a Dialog on page as Rails JS response?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery colorbox plugin as my popup/modal dialog box solution in my site. When I give a js response to client, I want to open a popup box. I wrote the following code in my response1.js.erb

```
$.colorbox();
```

I am getting the response correctly from server but while it is getting executed on the browser, firebug reports error like

```
$.colorbox() is not a function
```

how else can I do the task? please help. All my related javascripts(jquery,colorbox) are getting loaded properly when the page loads (i checked the page source html file)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you are using `format.js` which calls your `page.js.erb` ? I do have an issue when I use `$.colorbox({html:'<p>testing 123..</p>'})` right in my document ready of my app, saying that `$box` is not defined. Not sure why that is. But in regards to what I can see from your limited example, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Colorbox JS file is being loaded before your call to `$.colorbox()`. If you reference that function before it is added to the jQuery object then it won't be available. You should also ensure that `$` refers to jQuery in the context you're using it in. If it is referring to Prototype instead then you might get that error. Also if you happen to be loading jQuery twice, then the jQuery object loses it's extensions which were loaded before the last time jQuery is included in the page. Some jQuery plugins like to include jQuery in their minified or packed distributions - this is bad form - however, it can often cause this problem. So make sure your libraries don't include jQuery after you've already done so.

The best way to ensure that `$` is always referring to jQuery is to enclose it in a closure like this:

```
(function($){
  // notice the $ argument of the anonymous function
  $('#dollarsign').is('.jQuery');
  // this last line executes the anonymous function and passes in jQuery as $
})(jQuery);
```